# Non-parametric and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have two question to the following code.

> **First**

What is the difference between CASE1 and CASE2? I can see that CASE2 fails to compile because of the missing non-parametric constructor. Why CASE1 compiles?

> **Second**

What is the difference between CASE3 and CASE4? Why is the copy-constructor nor assignment operator called? According to [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) tutorial the copy constructor is called

> when instantiating one object and initializing it with values from
>   another object

which is exactly what happens in these cases. Note that

> CComplexNumber e=c;

is conceptualy the same as CASE3 but here the copy constructor is called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CComplexNumber  {
    float m_realPart;
    float m_imagPart;
public:
    CComplexNumber(float real, float imaginary) : m_realPart(real), m_imagPart(imaginary) {
        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    CComplexNumber(const CComplexNumber & copy) {
        cout<<"Copy constructor called"<<endl;
        this->m_realPart=copy.m_realPart;
        this->m_imagPart=copy.m_imagPart;
    }

    CComplexNumber& operator=(const CComplexNumber& rhs){
        cout<<"Assignment operator called"<<endl;
        this->m_realPart=rhs.m_realPart;
        this->m_imagPart=rhs.m_imagPart;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const CComplexNumber& rhs){
        out<<"["<<rhs.m_realPart<<","<<rhs.m_imagPart<<"]";
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    CComplexNumber a(); //CASE1
    //CComplexNumber b; //CASE2

    CComplexNumber c=CComplexNumber(3,4); //CASE3
    CComplexNumber d(CComplexNumber(5,6));//CASE4

    cout<<a<<"|"<<c<<"|"<<d<<"|"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
1|[3,4]|[5,6]|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CComplexNumber a(); //CASE1
```

This is not an object creation.  It is a function declaration.  You are declaring a function named `a`, which takes no parameters and returns a `CComplexNumber`.

As for the rest, it's called [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). The compiler is free to eliminate unnecessary calls to the copy constructor even if those calls would have side effects.

Comment: And I believe CASE2 doesn't compile because the default constructor hasn't been implemented, and wasn't implicitly generated because of the other constructor.

Comment: @maditya: Yep, but the OP knew that, I think. Non-parametric constructor is his fancy way of saying default constructor.

Comment: Why then the "cout<<a" line prints out "1"?

Comment: @Slazer: In that statement, `a` is implicitly converted to a bool with the value of `true`, which prints as 1. Try this (after including `<iomanip>`: `cout << boolalpha << a;`

Comment: @Slazer: It's in contrast to a null function pointer, which converts to false.  This is useful if you have a function which takes a function pointer as a parameter, calling the function if there is one, or performing some other action if there's not.